Transform excel default en_US CI to binary
I am making a Tableau dashboard where I am looking for matches between internal data and external database of entities. The issues is that the internal data is coming from SQL and is binary format and the joined data is from excel in en_US CI format. This creates collation error.
Is there a way to transform excel file to binary format before joining?
If not, is there any other procedure that deals with this issue?
The excel data looks something like this:



Id
Entity Name




56238712
Entity 1


42346715
Entity 2


27841562
Entity 3




can you provide an example of the SQL binary output you're seeing?

I am not sure if this is ideal solution. But to avoid the issue I created calculated field str([columne_name]).
